# postgresql window functions count

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I can this query `SELECT COUNT(*) OVER(), id, name, date... FROM table WHERE user_id = 1 LIMIT 20, OFFSET 0` I need the count for pagination, how does this work? does count gets computed for each row or just a single time?

Does it affects index uses, as I know functions can sometimes affect index uses but mostly in where clauses.

Are there any performance penalties of doing it like this instead of the 2 separate queries (count and then data retrieve)? I would not do a sub query as that will run for each row.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a window function is more efficient than running two queries. There is no possible influence on index usage.

Window functions are calculated *after* the result set has been generated, but before `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. The result is added as an extra column to each row.

I cannot see how the total count you are calculating with this window function will be useful for pagination.

As an aside, using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` is pointless without an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: well, if you want to generate pagination links like, "last" you need to know the total.